# How can I make PHP:s setlocale() to work correctly on localhost?

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to output the current date with different languages. I have used the following code to echo the date 2022-01-01 in Swedish natural language:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sv_SE.UTF-8');
echo strftime("%A %e %B %Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2022)) . "<br>";
?>
```

When this code is run on my web server it shows the expected output in Swedish:

```
lördag 1 januari 2022
```

But when testing on my localhost it displays the date is written in English:

```
Saturday 1 January 2022
```

I am running Apache on my localhost. I guess that I need to configure Apache or PHP locally to make this work. But I am not sure how or where. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's dependent on the underlying OS, so make sure you have that locale installed on the OS you're using.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Actually it's a Swedish version of Windows 11. So the OS has the expected language I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer now. It seems that Microsoft uses other locale strings for this. For Swedish it shall be "sve_SWE" instead of "sv_SE".

Read more: [MS Language strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/39cwe7zf(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), and [MS Country/Region strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/cdax410z(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

So, for a Windows version of localhost it should be:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sve_SWE.UTF-8');
```